# SlickJS slides not working after API call

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I have a problem with `slickjs`. My app is fetching data from weather API. ANd i want to put this data into sildes. Sildes are created by `forEach` and template string. Issue is that slickjs requires to apply it's container to parent elemnt that i am inserting my slides and that is ok. But if slides are created after certain event in my case fetching data by user slickjs doesn't see my slides and do not apply class to them to work. But if i re-size the page it for browser to parse JS and apply those classes so slider is working.

**app.js**

```
import { fetchForcast } from './fetch'
import { ui } from './ui'



let btn = document.getElementById('btn')

btn.addEventListener('click', getWeather)

function getWeather() {

    let city = document.getElementById('city').value
    let country = document.getElementById('country').value

    fetchForcast.fetchCall(country, city)
        .then(res => ui.showWeather(res.resData))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    fetchForcast.fetchCurrent(country, city)
        .then(res => ui.showCurrent(res.resData))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));

}

$(window).on('load', function() {
    window.slickSettings = {
        autoplay: false,
        autoplaySpeed: 4000,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        dots: false,
        arrows: false,
        responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 990,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 2
                }
            }, {
                breakpoint: 550,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                }
            }

        ]
    };
    $('.forcast').slick(window.slickSettings);
})
```

**UI class**

```
 class UI {
     showCurrent(weather) {
         let rain = weather.weather[0].main

         if (rain === "Rain") {
             document.body.style.background = "url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/459451/pexels-photo-459451.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=black-and-white-clear-cool-459451.jpg&fm=jpg')";
         }
         let output = ''
         output += `

         <div class="current__weather-box">
         <h5 class="city">${weather.name}</h5>
         <span class="country">${weather.sys.country}</span>
         <span class="desc">${weather.weather[0].description}</span>
         <ul>
             <li><span>humidity:</span><span>${weather.main.humidity}%</span></li>
             <li><span>temperature:</span><span>${weather.main.pressure}</span></li>
             <li><span>temperature:</span><span>${weather.main.temp}</span></li>
             <li><span>max:</span><span></span>${weather.main.temp_max}</li>
             <li><span>min:</span><span></span>${weather.main.temp_min}</li>

         </ul>
     </div>

              `
         document.getElementById('current-weather').innerHTML = output
     }
     showWeather(weather) {

         let output = ''

         let forcasts = weather.list.slice(1, 5)
         forcasts.forEach(forcast => {
             output += `
             <div class="forcast__box">
             <span>${forcast.dt_txt}</span>
             <ul>
             <li>${forcast.weather[0].description}</li>
                 <li>${forcast.main.humidity}</li>
                 <li>${forcast.main.pressure}</li>
                 <li>${forcast.main.temp}</li>
                 <li>${forcast.main.humidity}</li>
             </ul>
         </div> `
         })
         document.getElementById('forcast').innerHTML = output;
         $('.forcast').slick('resize');
     }
 }

 export const ui = new UI()
```

**slickjs**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.forcast').slick({
        autoplay: false,
        autoplaySpeed: 4000,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        dots: false,
        arrows: false,
        responsive: [{
                breakpoint: 990,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 2
                }
            }, {
                breakpoint: 550,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                }
            }

        ]

    });

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your slickSettings in a global var (actually in a var that's available everywhere you need to initialize a slick instance):

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  window.slickSettings = {
    autoplay: false,
    ... // <= rest of your slick settings
  };
  $('.forcast').slick(window.slickSettings);
})
```

... and, in your ajax call, reinitialize slick with same settings:

```
... {  ...
  document.getElementById('forcast').innerHTML = output;
  $('.forcast').slick(window.slickSettings); // <= add this line
  ...
}
```

**Note:** You don't ***really*** need to polute `window` object with that property and your settings may well just live in a separate variable but, since I don't know anything about your system, the one above will surely work. In general, you want to avoid adding properties to window object and try to limit the scope of your variables to what they need in order to do the job.

---

Another option is to trigger `resize` event on `window` after you update the html. Not on `.forcast`!  [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) event does not bubble and should only be placed on `window` object:

> *Only handlers registered on the window object will receive events.*

---

Looking closer at the examples pages, you have `slickAdd` method:

```
$('.forcast').slick('slickAdd',output);
```

... but for this to work `output` only needs the additional slides.

---

It also appears that this also works:

```
$('.forcast')[0].slick.refresh();
```

Comment: not working, added more code into question please take a look

Comment: I added more options, based on what I found. I won't be able to look at this for another hour or so. Hope you fix it with the additional methods.

Answer (score 0):

you could manually trigger the resize event after inserting the markup into the DOM to enforce slick to reinit

```
  $('.forcast').slick('resize');
```

or just wait with initializing slick.js until the DOM creation is finished. 
now you initialize slick on `$(document).ready()` which is called before the ajax call is finished.

Comment: Please read [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize).